# How do I parse out specific dataframes when using pandas to web scrape data from a page with multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, datatable

I'm working on a project that will scrape data off of https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2021/opp.htm.  When you visit this webpage you'll see that there are multiple  tables.  I can obtain the first table with no issues when I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
year=2021
defense_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{}/opp.htm'.format(year)
df5 = pd.read_html(defense_url, header=1)[0]
df5.head()
```

However, when I attempt to obtain data from the other tables by changing the index I get a table without a header or an error.  For example, `df5 = pd.read_html(defense_url, header=1)[1]` will create a dataframe without a header a (as shown in the image below):[image]

Additionally, `df5 = pd.read_html(defense_url, header=1)[2]` generates an IndexError (as shown below):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [46], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df5 = pd.read_html(defense_url, header=1)[2]
      2 df5.head()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone know what i could possibly be doing wrong here?

Comment: It's likely that the page loads asynchronously, so only the tables you scraped are present in the HTML until and unless the page is actually visited by a web browser. You might need something like selenium to create a full browser session in order to access all of the data. (Also worth noting that scraping is explicitly against the terms of service of the site in question)

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks for your answer.  I will look into selenium. The data on this site is free to use and scrap as long as you're not trying to profit from the data or hinder the website's performance.  Pro-football reference was recommended for this project for that specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the index error is because the html response only returns 2 `<table>` tags. So when you try to get the dataframe at index position [2] (the 3rd table), its not in the list of dataframes.

Those other tables are actually there in the html response but as comments. So there is 2 ways to get that:

1. Use BeautifulSoups function of pulling out the comments and parse those.
2. Simply remove/replace the html string that denotes commented html.

I'll code out both for you below:

**1. bs4 Comments:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd

year=2021
defense_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{}/opp.htm'.format(year)

df5 = pd.read_html(defense_url, header=1)

result = requests.get(defense_url).text
data = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')

comments = data.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

for each in comments:
    if 'table' in str(each):
        try:
            level = 0
            if isinstance(pd.read_html(str(each))[0].columns, pd.MultiIndex):
                level = 1
            df5.append(pd.read_html(str(each), header=level)[0])
        except:
            continue
```

**2: remove/replace the html string that denotes commented html:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

year=2021
defense_url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/{}/opp.htm'.format(year)

# Get the data
response = requests.get(defense_url)
html = response.text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')

df5 = pd.read_html(html)
```

Only difference between the 2 is the second option you'll need to do one more step to find which dataframes are multi-indexed and deal with those if needed.

**Output from option 1:**

```
print(df5[2])
      Rk                        Tm     G      Cmp  ...  Sk%  NY/A  ANY/A     EXP
0    1.0             Buffalo Bills  17.0    297.0  ...  7.3  4.80    3.8   20.04
1    2.0      New England Patriots  17.0    319.0  ...  6.3  5.50    4.5   -0.86
2    3.0             Chicago Bears  17.0    314.0  ...  9.3  6.20    6.7  -78.80
3    4.0         Carolina Panthers  17.0    337.0  ...  7.0  5.90    6.1  -47.59
4    5.0          Cleveland Browns  17.0    367.0  ...  6.9  5.60    5.5  -51.01
5    6.0       San Francisco 49ers  17.0    372.0  ...  8.1  5.90    6.1  -91.78
6    7.0         Arizona Cardinals  17.0    367.0  ...  6.8  6.10    6.1  -49.69
7    8.0            Denver Broncos  17.0    341.0  ...  6.0  6.10    5.9  -43.39
8    9.0       Pittsburgh Steelers  17.0    355.0  ...  8.9  5.90    5.7  -44.60
9   10.0         Green Bay Packers  17.0    379.0  ...  6.1  5.80    5.5  -33.40
10  11.0       Philadelphia Eagles  17.0    409.0  ...  4.7  6.10    6.1  -81.44
11  12.0      Los Angeles Chargers  17.0    357.0  ...  5.9  6.30    6.4  -89.74
12  13.0         Las Vegas Raiders  17.0    400.0  ...  5.5  5.90    6.4 -159.12
13  14.0        New Orleans Saints  17.0    369.0  ...  7.2  6.00    5.3   -1.74
14  15.0           New York Giants  17.0    402.0  ...  5.3  6.00    5.7  -56.19
15  16.0            Miami Dolphins  17.0    373.0  ...  7.3  5.90    5.6  -26.14
16  17.0      Jacksonville Jaguars  17.0    377.0  ...  5.6  6.70    7.0 -137.16
17  18.0           Atlanta Falcons  17.0    391.0  ...  3.0  6.60    6.8 -119.11
18  19.0        Indianapolis Colts  17.0    390.0  ...  5.2  6.30    6.0  -73.90
19  20.0            Dallas Cowboys  17.0    364.0  ...  6.3  6.20    5.1   13.82
20  21.0      Tampa Bay Buccaneers  17.0    445.0  ...  6.5  5.60    5.3  -30.09
21  22.0          Los Angeles Rams  17.0    416.0  ...  7.4  6.10    5.3  -41.65
22  23.0            Houston Texans  17.0    363.0  ...  5.5  7.10    6.7 -131.46
23  24.0             Detroit Lions  17.0    359.0  ...  5.2  7.20    7.5 -161.97
24  25.0          Tennessee Titans  17.0    395.0  ...  6.4  6.20    5.9  -59.34
25  26.0        Cincinnati Bengals  17.0    420.0  ...  6.3  6.30    6.2  -67.23
26  27.0        Kansas City Chiefs  17.0    401.0  ...  4.8  6.70    6.5 -110.25
27  28.0         Minnesota Vikings  17.0    401.0  ...  7.5  6.40    6.1  -57.45
28  29.0  Washington Football Team  17.0    400.0  ...  6.0  6.80    7.1 -142.08
29  30.0             New York Jets  17.0    401.0  ...  5.3  7.10    7.5 -198.18
30  31.0          Seattle Seahawks  17.0    443.0  ...  4.9  6.50    6.5 -126.34
31  32.0          Baltimore Ravens  17.0    397.0  ...  5.2  7.20    7.6 -166.26
32   NaN                  Avg Team   NaN    378.8  ...  6.2  6.22    6.1  -76.40
33   NaN              League Total   NaN  12121.0  ...  6.2  6.22    6.1     NaN
34   NaN                  Avg Tm/G   NaN     22.3  ...  6.2  6.22    6.1     NaN

[35 rows x 25 columns]
```